# In page error 0xc0000006

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a VS 2005 application using C++ . It basically importing a large XML of around 9 GB into the application . After running for more than 18 hrs it gave an exception 
 0xc0000006 In page error. THe virtual memory consumed is 2.6 GB (I have set the 3GB) flag.

Does any one have a clue as to what caused this error and what could be the solution

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could consider SQLite as an alternative to a 9gb xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are out of memory. Can you run it again on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Programs often do inexplicable things in response to OOM conditions. There is little to be gained from trying to figure them out, unless you have a requirement to run under low memory conditions

Answer (score 3):

0xC0000006 is `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR`. As people much wiser than me already say,  [When you start getting in-page errors on your hard drive, it's time to go shopping for a new hard drive](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200512-00/?p=103743).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but maybe it will help someone.

If you are getting this error while starting the application from a network drive, try setting linker flag /SWAPRUN:NET in your vc++ project.

Disclaimer: I found this solution [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081204-00/?p=19963#comment-689823)

Comment: More info about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050368/unable-to-start-applications-from-network-0xc0000006