# Unable to start applications from network "0xc0000006"

Tags: windows, networking

I can't start applications from a network share or drive. An error Appears saying that the application was unable to start 0xc0000006. If I copy the .exe on my desktop it works fine.
I tried to start Windows in safe mode and it works too.

My machine run on an HP laptop core i5 with Windows 7 SP1.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I found my problem: It's a bug that append sometimes with Kaspersky endpoint Security v.10. I just uninstall this version and install an older version (v.8). I hate Kaspersky...
Hope it will help someone!

Comment: If it only happens when running the shortcut, check the shortcut `start in` folder setting. If that was the issue however, running it straight from the drive (without a shorcut) would work.

Comment: This should be on [Super User](http://superuser.com), unless it's a programming question. But this doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Consistently happening when a) The app run from a file server AND b) the file server is rebooted. If that is the case, a (inconvenient / annoying)reboot fix the issue. In my case: no way to make the app local.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your replies.

I solved the problem by uninstalling Kaspersky end point 10.

My colleges have the version 10 of kasperky and it works but not for me.

I will install an older version waiting for kaspersky v 11.

Answer (score 10):

0xc0000006 is an [`NTSTATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) code. Specifically it is `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR`.

It is not uncommon to see these errors when you attempt to run an executable from a network volume. For whatever reason, if there is any even intermittent problem accessing the network volume, then you may see this error. When a module is loaded, the code is not physically loaded until it is needed. A memory mapped file is created, and when a particular page is needed, it is brought into physical memory on demand. If your network fails to meet this demand, your application stops with `STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR`.

The common ways to deal with this include:

1. Getting a more robust connection to your network volumes.
2. Copying the executable file to a local drive and running it from there.
3. Adding the `IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` flag to your PE file options.

Comment: Plausible, but he has to be extremely unlucky to get this to strike consistently right after he starts the program.  This quacks more like malicious anti-malware or an odd permissions problem.

Comment: On number 3, what is a "PE file" and how do I set options on it?  I've done 15 minutes of googling and can't figure out where to stick this thing called "IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP". Is this a linker option?  A runtime setting? A VC++ setting?

Comment: @Tim It depends on the compiler and tools that you are using. However, judging from another comment, it seems that you found the option in the VS options.

Comment: Any method to clean the swap file without a reboot?